# Where to host Django project files on deployment server

Tags: django, django-deployment

New to Django here. I have developed a minimum working django website with Postgres as database back-end and nginx/gunicorn as web server on Ubuntu linux. Currently all the files are on my laptop in `~/workspace/djangoapp/src$` in my home directory. I want to now deploy the project to GCP. Which directory, on the production server, the files would go in? It can't be my home directory on the production server. Shouldn't they go in one of the system directories like /opt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to deploy your project on Google Cloud Platform, you should follow [GCP guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/python/django). There are step by step guide on how to deploy and run Django app on GCP as for example running "[Django on App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#console)".

It would be easier to follow the GCP guides for your production server.